# Where does Trac store its environment information

Tags: linux, ubuntu, trac, issue-tracking

Following an initial Trac installation on an Ubuntu 10.04 system, I was overwhelmed with the Plugins that were available.

Some theme installation was messing up my environments. So I removed my environments and tried to re-create them. But Trac still seemed to keep information on the installed environments and installed Plugins.

Even removing both installation and plugins didnt seem to work - doing a fulltext search over the whole 
 server didnt bring any results either.

Does anyone know where Trac stores the info on any created envinronment + plugins?

Answer (score 1):

Trac will pickup plugins from Python's `site-packages` directory, as well as the environment's `plugins` directory. One possibility is that the plugins are installed in a `site-packages` directory, but regardless you should be able to disable them through the web administration page, or by editing the `[components]` section of *trac.ini*. Documentation is available on the [TracPlugins](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracPlugins) page. Check if you have a [GlobalConfiguration](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracIni#GlobalConfiguration) if someone else setup the initial Trac installation.